# Route not defined when passing parameter to a route

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8, url-parameters, named-routing

I have a named route with a parameter which looks like this...

```
Route::get('/profile/{user_id}', [ProfileController::class, 'profile'])->name('profile');
```

Now in one of my controller,

I have a function that calls this route like this

```
public function _myFunction($some_data) {
    return redirect()->route('profile', [$some_data->user_id]);
}
```

and in my `ProfileController's` `profile()` function, I have this.

```
public function profile() {

    return view('modules.profile.profile');

}
```

I've followed the documentation and some guides I found in SO, but I got the same error,

```
"Route [profile] not defined."
```

can somebody enlighten me on where I went wrong?

Here's what my routes/web.php looks like...

```
Route::middleware(['auth:web'])->group(function ($router) {

    Route::get('/profile/{user_id}', [ProfileController::class, 'profile'])->name('profile');

});
```

Comment: did you cache your routes? is this route you are showing in a route group up the line that defines a 'name'/'as'?

Comment: @lagbox Yes, I already did. BTW, I noticed something strange, I tried removing the parameter in the routes and call it normally like `redirect()->route('profile')`,  I noticed that it has a hash at the end of the URL. it looked like this : `mysite.com/profile#`

Comment: Are you sure your user is logged in? Your route needs authentication.

Comment: @FaridVatani Yes I'm logged in, I tried using `dd` on all calls, and I noticed that it did not go through the `ProfileController's` `profile()` function

Comment: OK, Where is  `$router` parameter used in routes group? If it is not used anywhere, clean it.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the route, you should pass the name of the attribute along with the value (as key vaue pairs). In this case, your route is expecting `user_id` so your route generation should look like this:

```
return redirect()->route('profile', ['user_id' => $some_data->user_id]);
```

Read more on [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes) in Laravel.

Comment: Can you see the route when you run ```php artisan route:list```, with the name?

Comment: dangg, I did a bad job posting half assed data here in SO. I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, and its really my bad for not providing a more specific case information and made you guys confused.

I was using socialite and called `_myFunction()` inside the third party's callback..

After all, the problem was the socialite's google callback, instead of placing the `return redirect()->route('profile', [$user->id])` inside `_myFunction()`, what I did was transfer it to the callback function.

So it looked like this now...

```
private $to_pass_user_id;
public function handleGoogleCallback()
{
    try {

        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

        $this->_myFunction($user);

        return redirect()->route('profile', [$this->to_pass_user_id]);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        dd($e->getMessage());

    }
}

public function _myFunction($some_data) {
 
    ... my logic here
    $this->to_pass_user_id = $some_value_from_the_logic
}
```